# visualisation of asymmetric Directed acyclic graph

Tags: visualisation, graph, graphics

I have got a data set, it represents the time take taken to get between different nodes on a graph, I have a valid X/Y pair for each node location.  The cost of getting between each node is asymmetric,  i.e. the cost off getting from A to B is different from getting from B to A.

I am trying to find a way of visualising this data set.
I did think of trying to draw a contour map, but the only methods I have found require a set of spot heights at given locations, when my data set is more like a series of gradients at different locations.

Comment: You have failed to mention which GIS system you intend to visualize your data!

Comment: I was looking something like a jpeg image,  my data is held in a Postgis database, I had assume sometype of post processing is required I can use Arcgis, Python,C,C++,sql, java.

I am just looking for a method, product, Idea etc,

Comment: This [book](http://eu.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-1118845846.html) may be of interest to you?

Comment: @Hornbydd That book did not solve my problem, but it has proved useful, thanks for suggesting it.